# mod_rewrite rules problem

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have two simple mod rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule club/(.*)-(.*).html$ club.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule club/details/(.*)-(.*).html$ /club/details.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

The first one works, but the second dosent. I think the first override the second but I can`t figure out how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule club/(.*)-(.*).html$ club.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule club/details/(.*)-(.*).html$ /club/details.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Try with that.

Comment: After taking a closer look, it's your regular expression that's wrong and not mod_rewrite itself. Your first regular expression will match what you wanted to capture in the second one since you have (.*) which matches everything - and it matched "details/" also. I can provide you with the appropriate one, however you might want to try to fix your regexp yourself before getting the solution from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RewriteRule club/(.*)-(.*).html$ club.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule club/details/(.*)-(.*).html$ club/details.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a couple of things. One would be to reorder the rules:

```
RewriteRule club/details/(.*)-(.*).html$ /club/details.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule club/(.*)-(.*).html$ club.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Another would be to change the pattern so that forward slashes don't match the club name, like so:

```
RewriteRule club/([^/]*)-(.*).html$ club.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule club/details/(.*)-(.*).html$ /club/details.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```